# Single image feature reduction at inference time

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, feature-extraction

I am trying to train a SVM classifier using scikit-learn.. At training time I want to reduce the feature vector dimension.
I have used PCA to reduce the dimension.

```
pp = PCA(n_components=400).fit(features)
features = pp.transform(features)
```

PCA requires `m x n` dataset to determine the variance. but at the time of inference I have only single image and corresponding 1d feature vector.. I am wondering how to reduce feature vector at inference time in order to match the training dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all preprocessing modules in scikit-learn nowadays, PCA includes a `transform` method that does exactly that, i.e. it transforms new samples according to an already fitted PCA transformation; from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.transform):

> **`transform`**(*self*, X)
>
> Apply dimensionality reduction to X.
>
> X is projected on the first principal components previously extracted from a training set.

Here is a short demo with dummy data, adapting the example from the documentation:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(X)

X_new = ([[1, -1]]) # new data, notice the double array brackets

X_new_pca = pca.transform(X_new)
X_new_pca
# array([[-0.2935787 ,  1.38340578]])
```

If you want to avoid the double brackets for a single new sample, you should make it into a numpy array and reshape it as follows:

```
X_new = np.array([1, -1])
X_new_pca = pca.transform(X_new.reshape(1, -1))
X_new_pca
# array([[-0.2935787 ,  1.38340578]]) # same result
```

Answer (score 2):

After "training" the PCA (or mathematically speaking, after the dimensionality reduction matrix is computed), you can use the `transform` function on any matrix or vector with suitable sizes, regardless of the original data.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np

m = 100
n = 200

features = np.random.randn(m,n)
print(features.shape)
>> (100, 200)

# Learn the PCA
pp = PCA(n_components=50).fit(features)
low_dim_features = pp.transform(features)
print(low_dim_features.shape)
>> (100, 50)

# Perform dimensionality reduction to a new sample
new_sample = np.random.randn(1, n)
low_dim_sample = pp.transform(new_sample)
print(low_dim_sample.shape)
>> (1, 50)
```

Comment: Well, 30 sec difference in answering...! :)

Comment: After 4 hours with no answer! haha

Answer (score 1):

PCA can work perfectly fine for this case. It doesn’t matter whether you have a single image at test time or not. Assuming your training set is 100 samples by 1000 features. Fitting PCA on the training set will give you 1000 x N eigenvectors because you will have 1000 by 1000 covariance matrix. And through eignedecomposition you will have to select only a fraction of the eigenvectors. Say you select only 25, you will have 1000 x 25 eigenvectors. At test time, with a single example of 1 x 1000 features, you only need to project features to the eigenspace of 1000 x 25 and you eventually get 1 x 25 reduced features (your features will now be a dimension of 25 features). So your training set will have 100 x 25 features and your single test sample will have 1 x 25 features. You can train and test any machine learning classifier with that.